# Typing errors for hoc with context

Tags: reactjs, typescript, higher-order-components

I'm trying to write reusable hoc for handling context data and prevent unecessary re-renders. It works alright but I have problem with typescript. Not sure if it is because my generic types in hoc or should I somehow give different typing in data component. I created sandbox with this problem and would be grateful for some help.

code:
hoc

```
export const withDataContext = <
  TProps extends unknown,
  TValue extends unknown
>(
  Component: ComponentType<TProps & Record<string, TValue>>,
  selectors: Record<string, (data: ContextState) => TValue>
) => {
  const MemoisedComponent = React.memo(Component) as MemoExoticComponent<
    ComponentType<Record<string, TValue>>
  >;

  return (props: TProps & Record<string, TValue>) => {
    const data = useDataContext();
    const contextProps = Object.keys(selectors).reduce(
      (acc: Record<string, TValue>, key) => {
        acc[key] = selectors[key](data);
        return acc;
      },
      {}
    );

    return <MemoisedComponent {...props} {...contextProps} />;
  };
};
```

components:

```
type DataComponentProps = {
  data: {};
  index: number;
};

export const DataComponent = ({
  handleFetch,
  handleDelete,
  data,
  index
}: DataComponentProps) => {
  console.log(data);
  return <p>{index}</p>;
};

export const DataWithSelectors = withDataContext(DataComponent, {
  handleFetch: (data) => data.handleFetch,
  handleDelete: (data) => data.handleDelete
});
```

Basically if I add handleFetch and handleDelete to DataComponentProps then I have problem in parent component as I don't pass handleFetch, handleDelete via props. If i remove them from types then I have problem with typing in DataComponent.

https://codesandbox.io/s/great-feather-b86c41?file=/src/dataComponent.tsx:42-472